# Move gravity forms element into another container

Tags: css, wordpress, gravityforms

What I need: To move the "Donation Amount" div(ID #Donation) into the "Dollar_sign" div(ID #Dollar)

I'm using wordpress and gravity forms; these are both gravity forms elements and I can't manage to append one element to the Donation Div; this would allow me to correctly keep the elements inline on mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply 'display: inline' to both elements?

Wrap both elements in a div with 'display: inline'?

Do you have access to the raw Wordpress files or are you just working through the Wordpress Dashboard/Back end?

Do you have a paid license to Gravity Forms? I've used their support with success before.